# SQL inner join returns duplicates in access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a mapping table(here for simplicity i displayed only records for **BNO=14M301**

```
  BNO   EID EDescription

 14M301 4010     W Harness
 14M301 5027    E Wiring part
```

And i have another table(Base) contains 7 records corresponding to **BNO=14M301**

```
  Prev      Base    Sufv    Sequence  CPSD    BNO        BNO-CPSC
  3M5T  14M301      AAB      234    180101   14M301      14M301-180101   
  3M5T  14M301      ABB      234    180101   14M301      14M301-180101 
  3M5T  14M301      SB       234    180101   14M301      14M301-180101 
  AV6T  14M301      DB       234    180101   14M301      14M301-180101
  AV6T  14M301      FB       234    180101   14M301      14M301-180101
  F1F1  14M301      AB       294    030304   14M301      030304-180101
  F1F1  14M301      BA       294    030304   14M301      030304-180101
```

Here i'm joining two tables with **BNO**. I'm using innerjoin. It is retrives 14 records instead of 7 i.e BNO-14M301=14times . but in **Base** table it contains only 7. My query

```
SELECT Base.Prev, Base.Base, Base.Sufv,Base.Sequence, Base.CPSD, Base.BNO, Base.[BNO - CPSD], Mapping.EID AS [E ID], Mapping.[EDescription] AS [E Description]
FROM Base INNER JOIN Mapping ON Base.BNO = Mapping.BNO WHERE (((Mapping.EID) Is Not Null));
```

Comment: and what is the output of that? What is the output you actually wanted?

Comment: Your query joins each of the 2 rows from the mapping table with the seven rows in the Base table, which gives you a total of 14 rows, what is the result you're seeking?

Comment: Maybe the results are not what you wanted. You have 2 records with BNO 14M301 and they each returned seven records. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If **14M301** contains only **4010** i.e mapping table contains only one **14M301**, is it returns only 7 records. Because of in mapping table 14M301 has duplicate records it returns 14 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The BNO `14M301` appears in your mapping table twice.  Thus, when you join to the `Base` table, you get all 7 records twice (once for each joined row in the mapping table).